# unity android crash - UI LayoutUtility GetLayoutProperty

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine

When running my program on my android tablet, it will inconsistently crash when starting up, or just as I am about to share a screen shot to social media using a plugin.

The device I am using is on android kit kat 4.4 and I am building from unity 5.3.4.

I get the log file from Unity. I get these few lines before the program crashes

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at UnityEngine.UI.LayoutUtility.GetLayoutProperty (UnityEngine.RectTransform rect, System.Func`2 property, Single defaultValue, ILayoutElement& source) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at UnityEngine.UI.LayoutUtility.GetLayoutProperty (UnityEngine.RectTransform rect, System.Func`2 property, Single defaultValue) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at UnityEngine.UI.LayoutUtility.GetMinHeight (UnityEngine.RectTransform rect) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at UnityEngine.UI.LayoutUtility.GetMinSize (UnityEngine.RectTransform rect, Int32 axis) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at UnityEngine.UI.HorizontalOrVerticalLayoutGroup.CalcAlongAxis (Int32 axis, Boolean isVertical) [0x00000] in :0

Is there any solution to this issue?

thanks in advance
-phil

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the layout you are accessing is null. Check that you find/set the proper element in the inspector.

Thanks.